# Unable to create table in Hive for csv file

Tags: hadoop, hive

Using below command to create table in hive but giving error.

```
CREATE TABLE TestData ( id1 int, id2 int, id3 int, id4 String) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ‘,’ stored as textfile;
```

Error

```
FAILED: ParseException line 1:106 mismatched input ',' expecting StringLiteral near 'BY' in table row format's field separator
```

I have tried '\054' instead of ',' but not working.

Comment: most likely cause of the issue would be  ' ,' is not correct

Answer (score 0):

You Didn't Mentioned How Rows are Separated..

**Edit:**
i.e. Lines

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time things which are not visible from open eyes , can be seen through vi editor ;) . There are `control characters` in command.

```
cat -v file.txt 
    CREATE TABLE TestData ( id1 int, id2 int, id3 int, id4 String) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY M-bM-^@M-^X,M-bM-^@M-^Y stored as textfile;
```

Solution - don't copy paste command, just type it.

Answer (score 0):

String type contains two data types in hive: VARCHAR and CHAR.
Instead of String use either **VARCHAR** or **CHAR**as data type as this will resolve your issue.

*also don't forget to mention the size while specifying varchar.

Example:   `CREATE TABLE TestData ( id1 int, id2 int, id3 int, id4 varchar (65355)) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ‘,’ stored as textfile;`

Comment: It does not resolve the problem till junk characters are there in query.